# twitter bootstrap: align element to bottom

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment, vertical-alignment

I have a three column layout, in each of them I have a button that I'd like to be at the bottom, at the same height in every column, like this:

```
  col1 header       col2 header       col3 header  
content content   content content   content content
content content   content content   content content
content content   content content   content content
content content                     content content
content content                     content content
                                    content content
                                    content content

   <button>          <button>          <button>
```

I want the three buttons to be aligned at the bottom, according to the column with the longest content.

My html looks like this:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <h2>col1 header</h2>
  <p>content [...]</p>
  <p class="text-center">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">button</a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <h2>col1 header</h2>
  <p>content [...]</p>
  <p class="text-center">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">button</a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <h2>col1 header</h2>
  <p>content [...]</p>
  <p class="text-center">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">button</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

More over this is responsive, so when the display si to narrow every column just appears one below the other.

Can anyone provide me some tip?

--
have a look at this related question: [Bootstrap: align elements to bottom of column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26268272/bootstrap-align-elements-to-bottom-of-column/26268491)

and the solution I found: http://www.bootply.com/mSxIMFgHSi#

Comment: you can calculate height of each div using jquery and simultaneously compare with another one. Take a variable to store maximum height value out of two compared div. Once you have maximum height of the div, you can easily put a css for button.

Comment: I was hoping to find a way to do it with plain css, no js

Answer (score 1):

## Solved It

---

### version 1 - using only css

try using `display`: `table`, `table-cell`, and `table-row`

### [only css demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DVE4f/189/)

### [only css fullscreen](http://jsfiddle.net/DVE4f/189/embedded/result/)

**css**

```
    .wrapper {
        display:table;
        border-collapse:collapse;
    }
    .wrap {
        display:table-row;
    }
    .item {
        display:table-cell;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        padding-bottom:50px;
        position:relative;
    }
    a.btn{
        position:absolute;
        bottom:10px;
        left:40%;
    }
```

---

See this explaination(save this image if it is not readable)

---

> ### Reference Blogs
>
> - [Equal height boxes with CSS](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200405/equal_height_boxes_with_css/)
> - [Fluid Width Equal Height Columns](http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/)

---

[image: same height image explaination]

---

### version 2 using jquery

You can do it using little jQuery

```
var maxHeight = 0;

$("div").each(function(){
   if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) { maxHeight = $(this).height(); }
});

$("div").height(maxHeight);
```

## [jQuery Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DVE4f/182/)

## [jQuery Fulscreen](http://jsfiddle.net/DVE4f/182/embedded/result/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I don't want to fix the height, I want the height to adjust to the column with the longest content. besides, in narrow mode, I don't want any blank space between the content and the button

Comment: I made a bootply with what I'm trying to achieve (inspired in your answer, obviously) http://www.bootply.com/Muh7eahFC8# Is there some way to avoid specifying the height and have it automatically adjust to the contents?

Comment: I was trying to avoid js, but I'll give it a try. In the meantime, I found this solution: http://www.bootply.com/mSxIMFgHSi# using display: table, but I had to hardcode the 33% width of each column... seems like there's no perfect solution...

Comment: nope, seems like the hardcoded 33% is the best options so far... I was thinking about trying with display: table-footer-group that sounds like it might do the trick...