# Bootstrap: align elements to bottom of column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment

To explain it in a short way, this is what I'm trying to achieve: http://www.bootply.com/Muh7eahFC8#

A responsive design, with three columns, and a button at the bottom of each column.

The problem is that I'm setting the height of the columns manually, and I'd like the whole thing to automatically adapt to the longest content of the three column.

Right now, I'm setting a different height based on the size of each viewport:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {
  div {
    height: 180px;
  }
  div a {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -40px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {
  div {
    height: 140px;
  }
}
```

(Give it a try on different screen width)

I think that what I'm trying to achieve is pretty common. Isn't there a smarter wayt to achieve it?

-- edit

With @DavidG help I could fins a responsive solution: http://www.bootply.com/7C2WvyxNyZ
unfortunately hte 33% is hardcoded, if I change the number of columns I'll have to update the css, and I found NO WAY to center the buttons in each column

Comment: So you just want those 3 anchors to be at the bottom of the columns? And how would you like the page to look at smaller widths?

Comment: What if you created an additional row with the same inner columns and give it a bottom css property?

Comment: @Pete It wouldn't work responsively.

Comment: The bootply I provided works as expected, even at smaller widths (give it a try), the problem is that the height is hardcoded...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't remember where I got this snippet from but this will make your columns the same height:

```
.row {
    display: table;
}

[class*="col-"] {
    float: none;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Then with a couple of tweaks, you can force the anchors to be fixed to the bottom of the div.

http://www.bootply.com/crLlXiiKqk

Comment: Nice workaround, I'll give it a try. One thing I noticed, is that the width is no longer respected, that is each column should have the same width (col-md-4), but the first is wider, try it clicking on the mobile icon...

Comment: I added a media query to make it responsive. It works ok, but I'm amazed at how complicated it ended up being... hace a look at it: http://www.bootply.com/mSxIMFgHSi# unfortunately the 33% is hardcoded...