# How to make divs near eachother to have the same height with twitter bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page with a variable numbers of child divs, that depending on screen resolution they come 4 in a row (desktop), 3 in a row (tablet) or 2 in a row (on smartphones). But their content differ. How could I make divs that are in a line, have the same height? 
I have an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ncsyv10e/)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        asdfas<br />
        asdfas
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        asdfas
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        asdfas<br />
        asdfas
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        asdfas<br />
        asdfas
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        asdfas
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        asdfas<br />
        asdfas
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe you asking about ["responsive column resets"](http://jsfiddle.net/ncsyv10e/1/)? Other solution is to use jquery...

Comment: I'm opened to a jquery solution :D But I truly don't know where to start. Getting the biggest height and set it to all cols gets me too much white space.

Comment: I answered this a while back, this link may help http://stackoverflow.com/a/26268491/1663001

Comment: But I don't want them all to go in a line :| I have a maximum of 20 collumns.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, go for [display:flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes)
or [jquery grid layout plugins](http://jquery-plugins.net/category/grid-layout)

Comment: I think the best solution out there is flexbox, no jQuery only pure CSS3. A parent div with display: flex and all childs height 100%. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You should manually set the height of the divs. Find out what height (probably in pixels) is appropriate for the largest div, and then set them all to that size.

Comment: That gets me a lot of white space since there is a diffenrece of even 100px from the biggest to the smallest.

Comment: Isn't that inevitable? You have multiple rows of divs that are different heights. How are you expecting them to line up?

Answer (score 0):

Put an Id on the row class so you can use it as a selector

```
<div class="row" id=selectorID>
```

Then try add a min-height on the child divs

```
#selectorID > div[class^='col-']{ min-height: 200px; }
```